# What is a word for an adventure or escapade that is negative?

Tags: single-word-requests

I can only seem to find antonyms for this word which is not applicable because it certainly is not stagnation.

Comment: Are you looking for something like ***fiasco***?   Your question is a bit unclear. Can you provide some more details on what you’re looking for and perhaps a sentence showing how you’d use it.

Answer (score 0):

An *escapade* is generally negative (but you didn't specify what you mean by "negative").

1. A wild and exciting undertaking (not necessarily lawful)

   - adventure, risky venture, dangerous undertaking
2. Any carefree episode

   - lark [informal]

-- [WordWeb Online](https://www.wordwebonline.com/search.pl?w=escapade)

Answer (score 0):

A good word here is **[misadventure](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/misadventure)**.

Comment: A good answer here includes a dictionary definition.

Answer (score -1):

You could call such an adventure a **[caper](https://www.lexico.com/definition/caper)**.

> NOUN informal An illicit or ridiculous activity or escapade

Example sentences from Lexico:

> They spoil everything, from a night out at the pictures to a meticulously-planned **caper**, involving a rich Aunt and a rubber zombie mask.

> They are now doing time for their role in the **caper**.

Often associated with crime or heist themes, a caper can include a ridiculous adventure or mischievous plan.